# Solr wildcard search with 2 terms

Tags: solr, lucene, wildcard

I am trying to do a wildcard search in Solr.

I have the following documents
    'Foo shiny bar'     and
    'Foo walks into a bar'     and
    'The bar is located next to Foo'

I am trying to retrieve all the documents which contains the word foo and the word bar, but the words don't have to be next to each other.

If I do +Doc:foo* or 
        +Doc:bar* I get all 3 results

If I  do +(+Doc:foo* +Doc:bar*) I get no results

How do I perform a wildcard search on a document using 2 or more words that can occur anywhere in the document.

```
<fieldtype class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" name="string">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

Comment: Why would you even use a wildcard here?  Seems to me like `+Doc:foo +Doc:bar` should work just fine (assuming the field is analyzed with something like `StandardAnalyzer`, which I'm guessing is where your real problem is).

Comment: @femtoRgon I thought that too and I have tried +Doc:foo +Doc:bar but that also returned no results.  And the fields are analyzed using the standard analyzer

Comment: Something about how you are indexing them is almost certainly the problem, so you'd need to provide some more information on that.  I'll take a wild stab in the dark, though.  Are you using `StringField`?  If so, use `TextField` instead.

Comment: This is a solr.TextField.  Added in a bit of our config for this field.

Comment: What does the analysis page under Solr Admin say for the values for that field? Just searching for the values should do want you want (as already mentioned)

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I'm guessing you can't override the "string" field type.  Try giving your fieldtype a different name ("my_string", or something).

Comment: Tried the above and then decided to rebuild the index.  Not sure why but everything works now.  Thanks for the help!